# cakephp redirect button

Tags: database, cakephp, redirect

hi all i have page that has two buttons, one should allow the person go to the add page and continue adding to the database otherwise if they click the other button it goes to the index page.

currently they both just add the entered information into the database and refresh the page, so when a person clicks the type_2 button they aren't being taken to the index page.

here is the if statement in controller

```
if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
{ 
    if($this->params['form']['type_1'] == 'type_1') 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Fields','action' => 'add'));
        } 
        else if($this->params['form']['type_2'] == 'type_2') 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Templates','action' => 'index'));
        } 


}
```

here is the view

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));


    echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>'Name: '));
    echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label'=>'Description: '));
    echo $this->Form->input('templates_id', array('label'=>'Template ID: ', 'type' => 'text'));//this would be the conventional fk fieldname
    echo $this->Form->button('Continue adding fields', array('name' => 'type', 'value' => 'type_1'));
    echo $this->Form->button('Finish adding fields', array('name' => 'type', 'value' => 'type_2'));
    echo $this->Form->end();


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to use request instead of params

```
if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
{  
    if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add'));
        } 
        if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
        } 


}
```

Comment: You're totally right, overlooked you were using `$this->params` instead of `$this->request->data`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if conditions are wrong, you're checking for indices `['form']['type_1']` and `['form']['type_2']`, this should be `['form']['type']` in both occasions, and then you check for their value, so it becomes:

```
if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
{ 
    if($this->params['form']['type'] == 'type_1') 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Fields','action' => 'add'));
        } 
        else if($this->params['form']['type'] == 'type_2') 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Templates','action' => 'index'));
        } 
}
```